# Questions about Java Producer Consumer Solution

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am currently reading about the implementation of a Java Consumer-Producer solution from a book.

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    private IntBuffer buffer;

    public Producer( IntBuffer buffer ){
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void run(){
        Random r = new Random();
        while( true ){
        int num = r.nextInt();
        buffer.add( num );
        System.out.println( “Produced “ + num );
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private IntBuffer buffer;

    public Consumer( IntBuffer buffer ){
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void run(){
        while( true ){
            int num = buffer.remove();
            System.out.println( “Consumed “ + num );
        }
    }
}

public class IntBuffer {
    private int index;
    private int[] buffer = new int[8];

    public void add( int num ){
        while( true ){
            if( index < buffer.length ){
                buffer[index++] = num;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public int remove(){
        while( true ){
            if( index > 0 ){
                return buffer[--index];
            }
        }
    }
}

IntBuffer b = new IntBuffer();
Producer p = new Producer( b );
Consumer c = new Consumer( b );
p.start();
c.start();
```

Here are a couple of questions that I have:

1. According to the book, this method uses busy waits. Where does this happen? From what I can understand, a Busy wait occurs when a thread is in the process of waiting for another thread to complete its execution before it can resumes its own execution. By using the wait() method, doesn't the thread still technically wait until the notify() call is made?
2. Why does a synchronized add/remove method not solve the issue of access control? I thought the term synchronization prevented multiple threads from accessing the same code segment.
3. Why is there a while( true ) loop in both the add/remove method?

Comment: Your `3` answers your `1`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Isn't `while( true )` just *waiting*?. I mean he is not waiting for *any condition to come true*..

Comment: @TheLostMind The condition in the `if` within the `while`. Notice each of those `return`.

Comment: It's just waiting, yes, but also preventing the method from returning until the condition in the if() statement becomes true, at which point the then clause returns out of both the while loop and the method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Ah. I didn't see the `if` conditions properly.. Thanks :)

Comment: As for `2`, I'm pretty sure that's the final solution. The current solution you've outlined has problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. Essentially, while(true) is there to ensure that, once the buffer is full, each method will block until the other method is called. in other words, the Producer won't be able to produce another until one has been consumed by the Consumer.

It does this by continually checking for a change to the index value. In the add() method, for example, the method will never return as long as index is NOT less than buffer.length. Instead, it will keep on checking over and over until index IS less than buffer.length, which only happens once remove() is called.

1. This, then, is a busy wait. Meaning, you aren't actually using a wait and notify mechanism that parks threads, but one that polls, instead. You'll notice there's no mention of the wait() and notify() methods here - it just blocks threads by using while(true). It's not unlike the difference between polling a port and opening a socket and receiving an update from the server asynchronously.
2. Because these threads are intentionally blocking one another, you couldn't really get away with synchronizing the add() and remove() methods - it'd simply lead to a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand the busy wait issue with the code. However, in terms of synchronizing the add and remove methods, what is causing the deadlock?

Even with the while(true) loop, wouldn't the block on of the add method still allow the remove method to modify the bugger? Or is the buffer array itself blocked from access the add/remove method is in the while(true) loop?

In the end, I suppose wait() will actually free up resources rather than continuously occupy it with the while(true) loop.

Comment: If you synchronize the add() and remove() methods, the shared object they're using as the lock is 'this' (the specific instance of IntBuffer). Synchronizing thus prevents any method from this instance being called while any thread is still executing any synchronized method on this class. Since the call to add() blocks until the call to remove() from another thread, and synchronized prevents another thread from getting into remove() method, the add() will block forever.